# Fix chapters being on multiple lines in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

This is the first time I am facing such a probem with latex. In my table of contents, chapters are displayed on as many lines as the number of pages required to write them.

For instance let's assume chapter 1 takes 4 pages and chapter 2 takes 2 pages. Here is an overview of my table of content:

```
Chapter 1                                           1
      ..............................................1
      ..............................................1
      ..............................................1
      ..............................................1
Chapter 2                                           5
      ..............................................5
      ..............................................5
```

I have no idea why the table of contents is built like this, since chapters are created like this:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{Chapter 1}
\lhead{Chapter 1. \emph{Chapter 1}}
```

Thank you in advance for helping me identify and deal with this odd situation.

Comment: Do you really believe that the information you provided is enough to identify the source of the problem? Try to make a complete, small example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Without a minimal (non-)working example, it's hard to say whatever.

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you dont provide a MWE.

Comment: Look at the aux file and try to figure out where all these toc entries are coming from.

Comment: The template you are using is known for doing strange stuff, i wouldn't use it. Apart from that, nothing can be done here without more information. As bad as the template is, i never have heard of that.

Comment: unregistered user, last seen at the moment of posting the question. i vtc as unclear.